# Remove period before hyphen between initials in reference list (apacite)

Tags: hyphenation, apacite

How does one modify the bst file or make changes in order to remove the period between before the hyphen in the initials in the reference list? (using apacite)

I'm typesetting my sister's PhD thesis and her reference list is one similar to Plant Physiology style (it's the closest albeit quite different). I've done some modifications to my bst file and added renewcommands, but as to removing the period before the hyphen in the initials I'm pretty much stumped.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=14.5pt,left=4.45cm,bottom=3.25cm,top=3.25cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage[nodoi]{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    citecolor={blue!50!green},
    pdftitle={Sample},
}

\newcommand{\arab}{\textit{{A}rabi\-dop\-sis}}
\newcommand{\arat}{\textit{{A}\-ra\-bi\-dop\-sis tha\-li\-a\-na}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\APACrefauthstyle}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \Bem{#1}%             journal
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, {\bf{#2}}%  volume
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
  \else
    \unskip({#3}) %      issue number
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
  \else
    \unskip:~{#4}%      pages
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
The proposed function of AtAGP18 is the initiation of female gametogenesis \citep{Acosta2004}. For AtBGAL4, its reported enzyme activities include preferred cleavage at $\beta$-1,3- and $\beta$-1,6-Gal, but not to $\beta$-1,4-Gal \citep{Ahn2007}.

\bibliographystyle{myapacite}
\frenchspacing
\bibliography{samplebib}

\end{document}
```

And this is the samplebib:

```
@article{Acosta2004,
  doi = {10.1105/tpc.104.024588},
  year  = {2004},
  volume = {16},
  number = {10},
  pages = {2614--2628},
  author = {Acosta-Garc{\'\i}a, Gerardo and Vielle-Calzada, Jean-Philippe},
  title = {A Classical Arabinogalactan Protein Is Essential for the Initiation of Female Gametogenesis in {\arab}},
  journal = {The Plant Cell}
}

@article{Ahn2007,
  doi = {10.1016/j.phytochem.2007.03.021},
  year  = {2007},
  volume = {68},
  number = {11},
  pages = {1510--1520},
  author = {Ahn, Young Ock and Zheng, Meiying and Bevan, David R and Esen, Asim and Shiu, Shin-Han and Benson, Jonas and Peng, Hsiao-Ping and Miller, Joseph T and Cheng, Chi-Lien and Poulton, Jonathan E and Shih, Ming-Che},
  title = {Functional genomic analysis of {\arat} glycoside hydrolase family 35},
  journal = {Phytochemistry}
}
```

This is what I get:
[image: This is what I GET]

Whereas this is what I want:
[image: This is what I WANT]

PS: `\arat` and `\arab` are just macros I created since they occur frequently in the thesis and I don't want italicising every bit of Arabidopsis/thaliana occurrence out there.

Answer (score 2):

I think redefining \BHBI should do the trick for example something like:

```
...
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\BHBI}{-}
...
```

Citing apacite manual:

> `\BHBI` is the hyphen between initials.  Introduced for analogy with
>   `\BPBI` and `\BHBI` used for authors who have two or more first names
>   with a hyphen between them, e.g., `Jean-Paul Sartre`.  Default is a
>   period and a hyphen.

Comment: I did redefine the \BHBI but put it outside the \begin{document} environment and it did not work. Put it inside and it works. Heh. Cheers.